# Calculate how long it take to reach the goal

Tags: probability

Every match win, the player receives $320...

Every match lost, the player receives $150...

Who reach the target of $26.571 first wins the game...

Bearing in mind that a player will win 50% of matches, how many matches will be necessary to achieve the goal? (Remember, lost matches also generate money)

And if the player wins only 40%, 30%, 20%, and 10% of the matches?

Tks (and sorry for my english, im brazilian)

Comment: I'd like to play this match.Win money every-time!.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is to calculate the odds of the game ending after exactly $n$ turns, and find the expected value using $\sum n p(n)$. In order to find $p(n)$, we can try to calculate the probability $\overline{p}(n)$ that the game ends after **at most** $n$ turns, and note that $p(n) = \overline{p}(n) - \overline{p}(n-1)$.

So now we are left with finding $\overline{p}(n)$. My idea is to note that after that, the player will surely have $150n$ Dollars; we can find $k \leq n$ that is the minimal number of turns the player has to win in order to achieve the goal (basically $150n + (320-150)k \geq 26571$).

Now we can easily calculate the probability of the player winning exactly $k$ turns (using Bernoulli distribution); $\overline{p}(n)$ will be the sum of all of these probabilities for $k, k+1, \ldots n$.